# Install SNMP on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian-squeeze, snmpd

I know Debian Squeeze (v6.0) is EOL and LTS officially ended in Feb. However, i have a few squeeze server (cant be upgraded for now) and i must monitor those Via SNMP. My problem is that all squeeze mirrors were removed and i for the life of me cant find the snmp daemon. I tried using the Wheezy source list, but im getting errors about dependencies it needs but wont be installed (see below). I assume because i need to perform a glibc update, but i cant do that (and risk breaking its current apps) . Does anyone know where one can find just the snmp daemon for squeeze?

Thanks!

> root@localhost:~# apt-get install snmpd 
>   Reading package lists... Done 
>   Building dependency tree 
>   Reading state information... Done 
>   You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: 
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>    aptitude : Depends: libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.9.7.6) but it is not going to be installed 
>               Depends: libboost-iostreams1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not going to be installed 
>               Depends: libept1.4.12 (>= 1.0.9) but it is not going to be installed 
>               Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.4.5-8 is to be installed 
>               Depends: libtinfo5 but it is not going to be installed 
>               Recommends: aptitude-doc-en but it is not going to be installed or 
>                           aptitude-doc 
>               Recommends: apt-xapian-index but it is not going to be installed 
>               Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not going to be installed 
>    libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.11.3-4) but 2.13-38+deb7u10 is to be installed 
>    locales : Depends: glibc-2.13-1 
>    snmpd : Depends: libsnmp15 (>= 5.4.3~dfsg) but it is not going to be installed 
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

**Edit**

I just wanted to update to describe what i'm seeing. I have the correct entry and "apt-get update" runs without an issue. I suspect that the issue now is that i had run "apt-get update" using the wheezy source. How can i resolve this?

**source.list entry**

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze contrib main non-free
```

**Apt-Get Update**

> root@Localhost:~# apt-get update 
>   Hit http://archive.debian.org squeeze Release.gpg 
>   Ign http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/contrib Translation-en 
>   Ign http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/contrib Translation-en_US 
>   Ign http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en 
>   Ign http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en_US 
>   Ign http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/non-free Translation-en 
>   Ign http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/non-free Translation-en_US 
>   Hit http://archive.debian.org squeeze Release 
>   Hit http://archive.debian.org squeeze/contrib i386 Packages 
>   Hit http://archive.debian.org squeeze/main i386 Packages 
>   Hit http://archive.debian.org squeeze/non-free i386 Packages 
>   Reading package lists... Done

Answer (score 1):

https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive

> If you are using APT the relevant sources.list entries are like:
>   `deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ hamm contrib main non-free`
>   or
>   `deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ bo bo-unstable contrib main non-free`

Comment: Same issue. My source list now has "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze contrib main non-free". Im running "apt-get update" which  seems to go thru fine, but "apt-get install snmpd" returns the same error

Comment: Maybe because i ran an APT update using the wheezy source list? If so, how do i revert?